# Maximum likelihood estimate for uniform distribution

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood

I stumbled to understand how to compute the MLE when talking about uniform random variable (and more generally continuous ones).

The problem : Lets say we have 2 samples following the uniform distribution $X_i \; uniform([-a,a])$. The likelihood of the samples say 12 and 30 is defined by the probability to observe those sample given the parameters. So it is :

\begin{align}
P(X_1=12, X_2=30 \;|\;a)
\end{align}

But this is by definition =0. I know the procedure of considering the product of the densities and maximizing this, but I don't understand why mathematically this is equivalent.

Comment: Which is mathematically equivalent to which?

Comment: "The likelihood of the samples say 12 and 30 is defined by the probability to observe those sample given the parameters" I suggest you go back and check your definition. For continuous functions does it really say "probability"?

Comment: Hint: the _likelihood_ of the observation $(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2; a)$ has value $\frac{1}{(2a)^2}$ for some choices of $a$ and value $0$ for other choices of $a$. Can you figure out what these choices are (Subhint: the answer will depend on $x_1$ and $x_2$ in some way)? Can you sketch the likelihood as a function of $a$? Where do you think it might attain maximum value? (Subhint: no calculus need be harmed in answering this last query; just looking at the sketch should suffice.)

Comment: AlecosPapadopoulos : Why it is equivalent to consider maximizing the density against maximizing the probability to observe the samples. 
Silverfish : The probability to observe those sample given the parameter is 0. I don't understand why we have to consider densities here ( even if in the definition it says to ).
DilipSarwate : Yes I can figure out the result of maximizing the likelihood function, this is not totally my question but why do we actually consider densities here.

Comment: @user149705 "I don't understand why we have to consider densities" - because for continuous distributions, the probability of being any value in particular (e.g. $P(X=12)$) is zero. So we don't learn a lot by looking at probabilities. If $X\sim U(-1,1)$ we'd like to say $X=2$ is "impossible", and $X=0.2$ is "just as likely" as $X=-0.7$. But $P(X=2)=0$, $P(X=0.2)=0$ and $P(X=-0.7)=0$. More usefully, $f(2)=0$, $f(0.2)=0.5$ and $f(-0.7)=0.5$.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't read like you are asking for someone to complete a homework question for you, so I will be more generous than @Dilip and give you something of a solution. [Wikipedia's article on the likelihood function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) starts like this:

> The likelihood of a set of parameter values, $\theta$, given outcomes
>   $x$, is equal to the probability of those observed outcomes given
>   those parameter values

So your confusion is entirely understandable, because that summary is incorrect for continuous distributions. Later on the page it points out that you should use the **probability density function** instead of the probability function, if your variable is continuous.

In fact, each observed value is modelled as an independent, indentically distributed observation from the uniform distribution, $X \sim U(-a, a)$, which has PDF $\frac{1}{2a}$ for $x \in [-a,a]$ and zero otherwise. Your sample can be regarded as a single observation from a multivariate uniform distribution - effectively a vector, each of whose components (independently) have that uniform distribution. The joint probability density function for that vector of observations is, by independence, the product of the probability density functions for the individual sample observations. To perform maximum likelihood estimation, it is this *joint density* that we wish to maximise.

For your sample, $x_1 = 12$ and $x_2 = 30$, which I am regarding as a vector of observations, $\vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 30 \end{pmatrix}$. The likelihood function is the joint density, i.e. $\mathcal{L}(a|\vec{x}) = f_a(\vec{x})$. Rather than jump straight to how to find the answer, I want to explore a couple of values of $a$ that I hope you will find insightful.

**Try $a=20$**

The PDF of the uniform distribution will be $\frac{1}{40}=0.025$ for $x \in [-20, 20]$ and $0$ otherwise. The probability density of $x_1 = 12$ will be $0.025$ and of $x_2$ will be $0$, so the joint density of the sample will be $0.025 \times 0 = 0$. We have made the uniform distribution too narrow, so that one of our observed values is impossible, and the likelihood of this choice of parameter is therefore 0. We need to try a bigger value of $a$.

[image: Uniform distribution, a=20]

**Try $a=50$**

The PDF of the uniform distribution will be $\frac{1}{100} = 0.01$ for $x \in [-50, 50]$ and $0$ otherwise. The probability density of $x_1 = 12$ will be $0.01$, and so will be the probability density of $x_2=30$. The joint density will be $0.01 \times 0.01 = 0.0001$ or $\frac{1}{10000}$.

[image: Uniform distribution, a=50]

Can we do any better than this? At least this time the likelihood was more than zero. But it is small because our probability densities were small, and this happened because the uniform distribution's probability was spread out over a wider interval (the set of values for which the PDF is above zero, known as the "support"). Let's try narrowing that interval.

**Try $a=40$**

The PDF of the uniform distribution will be $\frac{1}{80} = 0.0125$ for $x \in [-40, 40]$ and $0$ otherwise. The probability density of $x_1 = 12$ will be $0.0125$, and so will be the probability density of $x_2=30$. The joint density will be $0.0125 \times 0.0125 = 0.00015625$ or $\frac{1}{6400}$. This is an improvement!

[image: Uniform distribution, a=40]

Can we do any better? We would like to make the joint density as high as possible in order to maximise the likelihood, and that means making the PDF of the uniform distribution higher. To achieve that, we want to use a narrower interval. But we already saw that if we made the interval too narrow, the likelihood becomes zero because it makes one of our observations impossible. How narrow can we make $[-a, a]$ before either $x_1=12$ or $x_2=30$ become impossible? Since our distribution is symmetric across 0, it is the observation which is furthest from 0 which is the problem (as you can see on the first graph). It will just sit inside the limits if we set our support to $[-30, 30]$.

**Try $a=30$**

The PDF of the uniform distribution will be $\frac{1}{60} = 0.01\dot{6}$ for $x \in [-30, 30]$ and $0$ otherwise. The probability density of $x_1 = 12$ will be $\frac{1}{60}$, and so will be the probability density of $x_2=30$. The joint density will be $\frac{1}{60} \times \frac{1}{60} = \frac{1}{3600} = 0.0002\dot{7}$.

[image: Uniform distribution, a=30]

This is the best we can do! If we make the interval any narrow, $a=30$ will lie outside the support, and the likelihood will fall to zero. So the maximum likelihood occurs at $a=30$, and this is our maximum likelihood estimate.

**A more useful approach**

I hope you can now see *conceptually* why the maximum likelihood estimator is $a=30$. You can't play around with graphs so easily in your exam so you probably want a more general, algebraic solution. Finding a formula for the likelihood function basically requires you to find a formula for the joint density function for your sample, which I'll now assume to be of size $n$:

$$\vec{x}=(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)^T$$.

Now the joint density is zero if any of these lie outside the support $[-a, a]$. So for a non-zero joint density we need $-a \leq x_i \leq a$ for each $x_i$, which is the same as demanding each $|x_i| \leq a$. With a bit of thought, this in turn is equivalent to demanding $\max(|x_i|) \leq a$. So long as we are in the domain, the marginal density for each $x_i$ is independently $\frac{1}{2a}$ and the joint density will be the product of $n$ such marginal densities, so $f_a(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{(2a)^n}$. Our final result is that:

$$\mathcal{L}(a|\vec{x})=f_a(\vec{x})=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{(2a)^n} & a \geq \max(|x_i|) \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$

In your example, $n=2$ and $\max(|x_i|)=30$ so you are faced with the task of maximising:

$$\mathcal{L}(a|\vec{x})=f_a(\vec{x})=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{(2a)^2} & a \geq 30 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$

You may have been trained to think "aha, maximising requires calculus" and try differentiating and setting to zero, but **don't do it**! The function isn't continuous at the interesting part. Instead you should draw a graph of the likelihood for a range of values of $a$. You should be able to deduce $a=30$ quite quickly.

**Code for plots**

```
require(ggplot2)

#output is probability density
fxa <- function(x, a) {
  ifelse(abs(x)>a, 0, 1/a)
}

#output is a function, PDF for this value of a
fx <- function(a) {
  function(x) fxa(x, a)
}

plota <- function(a) {
  x.df <- data.frame(x=c(12, 30))
  x.df$density <- (fx(a))(x.df$x)
  ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-50, 50)), aes(x)) + 
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.05)) +
    stat_function(geom="area", fun=fx(a), n=1e3, fill="grey") +
    geom_point(data=x.df, aes(x=x, y=density)) + 
    theme_bw() + ylab("probability density")
}
```

The graphs are generated just by specifying a particular value of $a$, e.g. `plota(25)`  for $a = 25$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right that the definition confused me a lot. Is the following reasoning valid ? I only consider the sample 12 here. We know that the probability of picking 12 in the interval [-x,z] is $\int_{x}^z \frac{1}{2a}dt = \frac{z-x}{2a}$. So if we try to maximize this value $\forall (x,z)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ we just need to maximize $\frac{1}{2a}$ which turns out to be the density. And then apply this treatment to a serie of sample by considering them i.i.d.

Comment: @user149705 If you use $U(-a, a)$ as your distribution, the support runs from $-a$ to $a$. Your formula for "probability of picking 12" is not correct, because in fact the probability of picking 12 (or any other specific number) is zero. Instead we maximise the probability *density* of picking 12: that's 0 if $12 \notin [-a,a]$ and $\frac{1}{2a}$ if $12 \in [-a,a]$. It's certainly no good picking $a=3$, for instance, since then $12 \notin [-3,3]$ and the probability density is 0. If you try $a=100$, so $12 \in [-100,100]$, the density of $\frac{1}{200}$ is small. Can you find a better $a$?

Comment: I think perhaps you have a problem with continuous distributions in general. For a pdf $f(x)$, the integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ finds the probability that $X$ is *between* $a$ and $b$. It doesn't find the probability of $X$ taking any particular value, because that is zero. Instead it considers a whole interval of values. But I congratulate you on an important insight: reducing this to a simpler problem, by using a sample size of 1, is a good way to get a foothold of understanding. Once you understand that case, then you can work up to larger sample sizes.

Comment: Oh yeah ! My mistake, I wanted to compute the probability of picking an interval [x,z] when working on the support [-a,a] where obviously $-a<x<z<a$. If we can prove that the probability of picking an arbitrary interval $[x,z]$ is always better for the parameter "a" than any other parameter, then this coincide with the definition of likelihood. It turns out that this is equivalent of optimizing the density function. I think I got it :). Thank you very much !

Comment: @user149705 I'm still not sure you've quite got it, because there isn't actually an interval you want to find the probability of. What did you mean by $x$ and $z$? Are $x$ and $z$ the values of your observations?

Comment: $[x,z]$ would be the interval you want to find the probability of under the uniform distribution with parameter $a$. If somehow you manage to find a parameter "a" for which $\forall$ interval, the probability is always bigger than with any other parameter, then you maximize the likelihood. By solving for $[x,z]$ you find out that you just need to maximize the density because $x,z$ are arbitrary.

Comment: @user149705 If we are attempting maximum likelihood estimation of $a$ given a sample $\vec{x}$, then there is no need to consider any interval whose probability we are trying to maximise. So I must confess I am confused what it would mean to solve for $[x, z]$.

Comment: Oh ok ! My reasoning is we are drawing sample from a uniform distribution with parameter $a$. To make that possible we have $a>max(samples)$. Then we are trying to maximize the probability of drawing any interval from this distribution. By doing that we are finding the most probable distribution from where the sample have been drawn from.

Comment: Right, this gets to the key point. In MLE, you're not trying to maximise the probability of "drawing any interval", you're trying to maximise the probability (or since this distribution is continuous, the probability *density*) of *your particular sample*.

Comment: I see. So as much as I can understand why we try to maximize the probability of a sample for the discrete case, I don't understand why we would be doing that for the density in the continuous case, since it doesn't give us any insight of how much the distribution is more probable to have generated the data. Or Am I missing something ? And if the distribution is not discrete nor continuous, how would we go about it ?

Comment: @user149705 Because in the continuous case, *probability density* is analogous to probability in the discrete case. Have a look at the final comment I wrote under your question. That explained why we use densities rather than probabilities fairly clearly, I hope.

Comment: Oh yea I just saw it. I understand now better. I guess we can reconcile the idea of probability by considering an interval $[12,12 + \delta]$ and making $\delta\rightarrow 0$. Optimizing for "a" would mean that this probability, as small as it get would be still larger than with any other parameter. Thank you :) I hope I didn't disturb too much your day !

Comment: @user149705 No problem. I think you've glimpsed the right idea, but you don't want to take $\delta$ all the way to zero: if you take the limit, the probability becomes zero too. The probability density is more like the limit of $P(X \in [12 - \delta/2, 12 + \delta/2])/\delta$ (the division is why it's called a "density", not just a probability). Then you can take the limit and you won't just get zero, you'll get something more useful.

Comment: To sum up, we want to maximize $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}P([12,12+\delta]) = \frac{\delta}{2a}$. Since this quantity goes to 0 we consider then optimizing $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{P([12,12+\delta])}{\delta}$. Hopefully I got it right this time.

Comment: @user149705 That's the right idea. I think you'll find it helpful to just conceptually switch to "probability densities" when considering continuous distributions - my earlier comment should have made it clear why the concept of "probability" of a single observation is not very interesting (probability of a whole interval makes sense, though). It is good to have some awareness of what the probability density actually means though.

Comment: Yes, I was before switching uncontrollably between pmf and pdf, and then when working with mixed distribution and odd-distribution, all my automatism fell off. Working on MLE now made it tricky for me to understand why we could switch pmf and pdf ( according to the defintion wikipedia gave me ).